# Как отредактировать плагин в Wordpress

Tags: php

Есть плагин для скрытия контента. Не могу изменить в нужную сторону. На каждой странице для скрытия нужно писать

```
[lock password=1234]контент[/lock]
```

Нужно чтобы я писал к примеру

```
[lock]контент[/lock]
```

а пароль задавал сам в PHP коде плагина.
Собственно сам код плагина:

```
<?php
class PartialPostPassword {

function PartialPostPassword() {

add_shortcode( 'lock', array(&$this, 'shortcode') );

  add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array(&$this, 'localization') );

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_lc-set', array(&$this, 'set_password') );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_lc-set', array(&$this, 'set_password') );

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_protectTinymceOptions', array(&$this, 'tinymce_options') );
add_action( 'admin_init', array(&$this, 'load_tinymce') );

}

function localization() {

load_plugin_textdomain( 'lc', false, '/locked-content/languages/' );
}

function shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
  'password' => false
), $atts ) );

if ( is_null( $content ) )
  return;

    if ( !$password )
    return do_shortcode( $content );

    if ( $_COOKIE['lc-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH] == sha1( $password ) ) {
    return do_shortcode( $content );
    } else {
      $label = 'pass-' . rand();
        return '<form action="' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="lc-set" />
    <div style="padding:15px 13px 4px; background: #333333;margin: 0 0 15px;"><p>' . __("Введите код доступа.", 'lc') . '</p>
        <p><label for="' . $label . '">' . __("Код доступа:", 'lc') . ' <input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" /></label> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__("Отправить", 'lc') . '" /></p>
        <p>текст, где нужно ввести код
</p>
        </div>
        </form>
        ';
    }
}

function set_password() {

  if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
        $_POST['post_password'] = stripslashes( $_POST['post_password'] );

setcookie( 'lc-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, sha1( $_POST['post_password'] ), time() + 864000, COOKIEPATH );

    wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_referer() );
    exit;
}

function load_tinymce() {
if ( (current_user_can('edit_posts') || current_user_can('edit_pages')) && get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
    add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', array(&$this, 'tinymce_add_plugin') );
        add_filter( 'mce_buttons', array(&$this,'tinymce_register_button') );
        add_filter( 'mce_external_languages', array(&$this,'tinymce_load_langs') );
    }
}

function tinymce_options() {
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../wp-includes/js/tinymce/tiny_mce_popup.js?ver=327-1235"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../wp-includes/js/tinymce/utils/form_utils.js?ver=327-1235"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../wp-includes/js/tinymce/utils/editable_selects.js?ver=327-1235"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="../wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">

      tinyMCEPopup.storeSelection();

                var insertProtect = function (ed) {
                    var password = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#lc-password').val());
                    if (!password) {
          jQuery('#lc-error').show();
          jQuery('#lc-password').focus();
          return false;
                    }
                    tinyMCEPopup.restoreSelection();
                    output = '[lock password="'+password+'"]'+tinyMCEPopup.editor.selection.getContent()+'[/lock]';

                    tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, output);
                    tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceRepaint');
        tinyMCEPopup.editor.focus();

                    tinyMCEPopup.close();
                };
            </script>
            <style type="text/css">
            td.info {
                vertical-align: top;
                color: #777;
            }
            </style>

            <title><?php _e("Lock This Content With A Password", 'lc'); ?></title>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none">
            <form onsubmit="insertProtect();return false;" action="#">

                <div id="general_panel" class="panel current">
                    <div id="lc-error" style="display: none;color:#C00;padding: 2px 0;"><?php _e("Enter a password!", 'lc'); ?></div>
                        <fieldset>
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="chat_width"><?php _e("Password", 'lc'); ?></label></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" id="lc-password" name="lc-password" value="" class="size" size="15" />
                                </td>
                                <td class="info"><?php _e("Enter your password for this content.", 'lc'); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <div class="mceActionPanel">
                    <div style="float: left">
                        <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="<?php _e("Cancel", 'lc'); ?>" onclick="tinyMCEPopup.close();" />
                    </div>

                    <div style="float: right">
                        <input type="submit" id="insert" name="insert" value="<?php _e("Lock", 'lc'); ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    exit(0);
}

function tinymce_register_button($buttons) {
    array_push($buttons, "separator", "lock");
    return $buttons;
}

function tinymce_load_langs($langs) {
    $langs["lock"] =  plugins_url('locked-content/tinymce/langs/langs.php');
    return $langs;
}

function tinymce_add_plugin($plugin_array) {
    $plugin_array['lock'] = plugins_url('locked-content/tinymce/editor_plugin.js');
    return $plugin_array;
}

}

$lc = &new PartialPostPassword();

?>
```

Comment: Вам нужно разобраться в [Wordpress Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) и самой структуре плагина. Конкретно вам потому что вряд ли у кого-то есть желание переворачивать такую гору кода. Надо просто где-то найти место генерации пароля и подменить.
p.s. `array(&$this, 'shortcode')`, `$lc = &new PartialPostPassword();` - роскошно!

Comment: Согласен с вами. Копаю код.
    array(&$this, 'shortcode'), $lc = &new PartialPostPassword();
Что с этим не так?

Comment: Автор пытается передать по ссылке объекты, которые и так передаются по ссылке. Толку от этого ноль, это не просто не работает, это не дает вообще никакого изменения в работе программы. Особенно радует &new, можно подумать, объект создатся, скопируется, а потом исходная версия будет удалена.